# How to get a value from slider when using Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

I really am struggling with js and Jquery mobile :(

-jquery-1.7.2.js

-jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js

- Chrome Version 20.0.1132.57

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('#temperature').change(function() {
    alert('.change() called.');
});
</script>
</head>
```

My html with jqm slider:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div>

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Conditions</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="temperature">Temperature: </label> <input type="range"
                name="temperature" id="temperature" value="15" min="-15" max="60"
                data-highlight="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[-----> My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samsam/6rT6P/)

Question1: Why this is not working if using jquery Mobile but without it is working?

Question2: What is the correct way to get a value from slider? I have tried many, no success.

Question3: Why this is alerting many times in Fiddle even if I change the value once?

Question4: What is the best way to get values when you have for instance 6 slider at the one page?

```
            **EDIT**
```

I changed it like that now, but same result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function valueChanged(){
    var SliderValue = $('#temperature').attr('value');
    alert("Slider value = " + SliderValue);
    console.log("SliderValue--->" +SliderValue);
}
```

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="temperature">Temperature22: </label> <input type="range"
                name="temperature" id="temperature" value="15" min="-15" max="60" onchange="valueChanged()"
                data-highlight="true" />
        </div>
```

And in the log I got:

> SliderValue--->16 conditions.html:22 SliderValue--->41
>   conditions.html:22 SliderValue--->41 conditions.html:22
>   SliderValue--->41 conditions.html:22 SliderValue--->41
>   conditions.html:22 SliderValue--->41 conditions.html:22
>   SliderValue--->41 conditions.html:22 SliderValue--->41
>   conditions.html:22 SliderValue--->41 conditions.html:22
>   SliderValue--->41 conditions.html:22 SliderValue--->41
>   conditions.html:22

So it just opens alert endlessly. Weird.

Thanks!
Sami

Answer (score 1):

A1: Just get it with `$('#temperature').attr('value')`
A2: -> `$('#temperature').attr('value')`
A3: I don't get it more than once!?
A4: Get every value in an function:

```
function getTemps(){                                             
      var temps = new Array[6];     
      temps[0]=$('#temperature1').attr('value');
      temps[1]=$('#temperature2').attr('value');   
      and so on...
}
```

Maybe that helps :)

Comment: Thank you! Try to keep your mouse on the result pane and move it and it is jumping all the time. Same happens in real app when I try it in Chrome. Are you trying to use onchange("getTemps();") for every slider or every of them once?

Comment: If you want to save them in the array on every change then add the `onChange="getTemps()"` function on every slider.

Comment: But I still don't get any second alert on Mac/Firefox :S

Comment: That's strange. I tried Fiddle with Firefox and I didn't get slider at all, just inputbox :) Did you try to put jquery mobile on, because that was the second problem that it is not working at all with jqm? I tried my software on Chrome and I got alerts endlessly.

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry, I don't get any slider as well. I was just focussing on the JS part...